# How can I search an application by specifying its name?

Tags: android, search

So I did that to get all the applications:

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent();
final List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getApplicationContext()
    .getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

How do I get a specific application by its name?

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374704/getpackagemanager-getinstalledpackages-packagemanager-get-activities-return/8501188#8501188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code for getting all application names installed on device in List. And you can query the list by name.

```
 PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
 Intent mainIntent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
 mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
 List list = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent , PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
 for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
     results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
         .loadLabel(pm).toString());
     Log.w("Installed Applications Names", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
         .loadLabel(pm).toString());
 }
```